# How does M:M relation in Power BI behave (cross join or simple filter)?

Tags: powerbi

Generally in a M:M relation I can think of this doing something like a cross join.

How does M:M relation in Power BI behave?

Is it a cross join or a simple filter just like how a 1:M would behave?

Comment: there is no M:M relationship only a M:N

Comment: and a M:N relationship is represented by a bridge ship

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: it is  still a M:N as it signals that there are different number of elements,and the document shows you bridge tables

Comment: It says the bridge table is an older solution. And the newer solution is to link it as many to many relation. My question is - does many to many result in a cross join or does it behave like the usual filter?

Comment: bridge tables are not old it is standard, creating new objects is in the trend right now but cause a lot of problems,  as they describe the same as bridge tables and ate bridge tables , but are not called so

Comment: My point is that power bi supports many to many relation. Is this like a cross join ?

Comment: no, the many to many Relationship is like the bridge table, a cross join is only good for few occasions